# Example of a function defined only in doman $>constant$

Tags: functions

Is there any function such that:

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    undefined, & \text{if $x<c$}.\\
    a, & \text{if x $\geq$ c}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a\space and\space c$ are constants and $c$ **may** or **may not** be $equal\space  to\space  0$  and  $a$ should **remain** constant throughout.

This may be a silly question but please answer...Thanks.

Comment: You have defined such a function in your question! Just let $c$ and $a$ be your favorite real numbrs.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well...no i mean a well defined function...(If you understand what i mean :-))

Comment: WHat you defined is a well-defined function.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well kind of like the answer given by oleg567!

Comment: **Absolutely** nothing is gained by doing silly things like that. If you really want that the functions be constant on $[c,+\infty)$, then the functions you wrote in your questions are actually **all** the functions that satisfy your conditions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Just curious! Nothing else

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=a\cdot\text{sign}(1+\sqrt{x-c}).$

$f(x)=a \cdot\bigl( \sin^2(\sqrt{x-c})+\cos^2(\sqrt{x-c})\bigr).$

Answer (score 2):

$\forall x, f(x) = a\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2}}$ is an example.

However keep in mind that the function you defined is a function.